# Using no-wrap whit fixed width CSS

Tags: html, css

I have to use no-wrap, but I have fixed width.

```
th, td {
    padding: 7px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-color: #00008b;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #deeff5;
    }

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #add8e6;
    }
```

White space problem can't just be ignored.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing ?

Comment: So it's the 3rd column which look bit expanded.. right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want columns to fit their content? Add to your css:

```
td, th {
    width: 1%;
}
```